# C# ternary use results of method (with datetime variable)

Tags: c#, datetime, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I have an issue that I'd like to work around

I have declared a nullable DateTime and I'm trying to put either a date in it or a null value using a ternary operator.

This does not work:

```
DateTime? date;
date = getDate() == DateTime.MinValue ? null : getDate()
```

My own code is a bit more elaborate but basically what I'd like to use is

```
date = getDate() == DateTime.MinValue ? null : resultofgetDate()withoutactuallyrunningitagain
```

I don't want to do the function twice, but in this case as a bonus, since it's datetimes, it also gives an error in the else section saying
`There is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'System.DateTime'` in my first example.

I'm not sure in what direction to look. I seem to need the opposite of the null coalescing operator (??).

Comment: Then assign it to a variable. Like `var dt = getDate();`

Comment: what's the return type of getdate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if `getDate()` is returning a `DateTime` and not a `DateTime?` (aka `Nullable<DateTime>`). The values used in ternary expressions have to be of the same type which is why you are getting your error.

Your first example should work with

```
date = getDate() == DateTime.MinValue ? null : (DateTime?)getDate()`
```

as pointed out in MaKCbIMKo's answer.

I'm assuming you return `DateTime.MinValue` as some sort of error handling / validation. If you change the method signature so it returns a `DateTime?` you can return `null` instead, then your statement becomes `date = getDate()`

Comment: This is the one that works for my example, even though I still have to run the method twice with this. It's not a problem because there is no other way. @MaKCbIMKo's solution is the one I ended up using, but yours is closer to the question so I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: You could always just save the result of getDate() in a temporary variable.

`DateTime temp = getDate();`

`date = temp== DateTime.MinValue ? null : (DateTime?)temp`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such operator. You can write something like this:

```
DateTime? date = getDate();
date = date == DateTime.MinValue ? null : date;
```

Comment: This is not correct. `DateTime.MinValue` is not `Boolean`

Comment: @afaolek You're right - accidentally submitted the answer while still writing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Please, do it [as Rob described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37461499/993547), but here is my take on an extension method:

```
public static T? Test<T>(this T? value, Predicate<T?> test, T? ifEquals) where T : struct
{
    if (test(value))
    {
        return ifEquals;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
DateTime? d = GetDate().Test(t => t == DateTime.MinValue, null);
```

Comment: Can `==` be used between `T?` and `T?`? ___Addition:___ Consider `Nullable.Equals(value, test)`, or drop the constraint and the four `?` and use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default(value, test)`.

Comment: No. It cannot ;) @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Now using a predicate, it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
DateTime? date;
var dt = getDate();
date = dt  == DateTime.MinValue ? (DateTime?)null : dt;
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create this extension method (one of the overloads calls the other one):

```
public static T? NullIfHasDefaultValue<T>(this T v) where T : struct
{
  return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(v, default(T)) ? (T?)null : v;
}
public static T? NullIfHasDefaultValue<T>(this T? n) where T : struct
{
  return n.GetValueOrDefault().NullIfHasDefaultValue();
}
```

Of course use it as `getDate().NullIfHasDefaultValue()`.